# ¿Cómo poder usar operadores con métodos genéricos (template class) en C#?

Tags: c#, template, genericos

Quiero hace una pequeña clase para comprobar variables. Básicamente para saber si su valor ha cambiado, si se ha incrementado o decrementado. En principio creo que solo lo voy a usar para variables tipo Float y Bool. El tema es que al empezar a hacerla el compilador me arroja el siguiente error y no encuentro la forma de poder hacer lo que quiero.

CS0019 C# El operador '!=' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'Type' y 'Type'

Este es mi código:

```
public class VariablesChecker<T>
{
    private T var;

    public VariablesChecker(T var)
    {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public bool wasChange(T var)
    {
        return (this.var != var);
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe como sería la manera correcta de hacer esto en C#?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: mas alla de la respuesta que te estan dando, estas usando una palabra reservada para darle un nombre tu parametro T, cambia el nombre de **var** por **parametro**, por decirte un nombre

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer esto que pretendes debes especificar que el **tipo de datos T implementa la interfaz IComparable**, es decir que se puede establecer una comparación ej. un **int**. Si **T** implementa esta interfaz entonces puede usarse el **método CompareTo**, este método devuelve **-1**, **0**, **1**, si devuelve **0** quiere decir que los elementos son iguales, lo cual quiere decir que no hubo cambio según lo que deseas hacer. Si son **1** o **-1** entonces un elemento es menor o mayor que el otro.

Entonces tu método quedaría así:

```
public bool wasChange(T var) where T:IComparable
{
   return !(this.var.CompareTo(var) == 0);
}
```

**where T: IComparable** es una restricción que indica que **T** puede compararse, este método pregunta si los valores han cambiado, de ser cierto retorna **true** caso contrario retorna **false**, el otro método también debe tener esta restricción, incluso esta restricción puede ser a nivel de clase si lo deseas.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esto en la página de Microsoft. Funciona pero me parece una forma inecesariamente rebuscada para algo que debería ser relativamente sencillo.

Este sería el código:

```
  public class VariablesChecker<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private T var;

        public VariablesChecker(T var)
        {
            this.var = var;
        }

        public void Update(T var)
        {
            this.var = var;
        }

        public bool WasChange(T var)
        {
           return this.var.CompareTo(var)!=0;
        }
    }
    VariablesChecker<bool> checkWayUp = new VariablesChecker<bool>(false);
```

Si alguien conoce una forma mas simple y la postea aquí le daré la respuesta por valida. Saludos!!

[Fuente:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-5.0)

Comment: La forma más simple es precisamente usar la restricción where T:IComparable, esto son conceptos un poco avanzados de programacion, busca en internet que es la varianza y la contra varianza y sus aplicaciones en c#

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es entender que quiere decir todo ese código, te puede resultar útil y aunque no lo creas hacer que tu código sea más legible y fácil de mantener, no es magia, es .Net