# ¿ Qué son las parametrizaciones previas de las clases y métodos en Java?

Tags: java

Es muy común emplear una **"parametrización previa" (desconozco el nombre técnico)** en clases y métodos de Java. Por ejemplo:

```
public static <Integer> String descodificar(){}
```

donde lo que llamo parametrización previa se refiere a la especificación del tipado "Integer". Mi pregunta concreta es:

**¿ Cómo se llama y cómo lo uso ?** Al no conocer el nombre técnico, doy saltos por la web sin éxito. Parece ser que se emplea para restringir el tipo de parámetros que puede recibir el método, pero tampoco lo tengo claro.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418818/c%c3%b3mo-poder-usar-operadores-con-m%c3%a9todos-gen%c3%a9ricos-template-class-en-c/418829#418829 entra aqui esta en c#, pero te puede ser util

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llama **Generics** ( java generics ). Permite definir clases y métodos genéricos en java. Lo que llamas parametrización previa se llama *parámetro de tipo*

Básicamente, se pueden definir clases que contengan campos de un tipo indeterminado (o subgrupo de tipos, ej:  < ? extends T> solo acepta objetos de tipo T o sus subclases) y al momento de utilizarlas se indica el tipo.
Recordar que los tipos son Clases o Interfaces (no tipos primitivos).

```
class Nombre<T>{
    private T campo1;
    private int campo2;
    
    public Nombre(T obj, int c2){
        campo1 = obj;
        campo2 = c2;
    }
    // definir get y set en usando T para campo1

    public T getCampo1(){ return campo1; }
    
    public void setCampo1( T campo1 ){ 
        this.campo1 = campo1; 
    }

    // definir métodos usando T o no
}
// crear una instancia de la clase
Nombre<String> nombre = new Nombre<>("ElNombre", 21);
Nombre<Integer> nombre = new Nombre<>(145, 21);
```

También se pueden definir métodos genéricos como el del enunciado, no es necesario que la clase sea genérica.

```
public static <T> String descodificar(T obj){
    // hacer algo con obj T
    return obj.toString(); // algo?
}
//uso
Clase.<Integer>descodificar(12); // retorna un String
Clase.descodificar(12); // el compilador infiere el tipo
```

Es un tema extenso y se puede utilizar de muchas formas. No se puede explicar completamente en una respuesta, tiene varios detalles a tener en cuenta.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, ya tengo una idea básica y sé por dónde empezar a indagar. No me queda muy claro qué has intentado explicar con el método "descodificar", pero ya indagaré y volveré a leer la respuesta. Gracias de nuevo.